# How to export local db file to heroku, Ruby on Rails 4? (Postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am now using Ruby on Rails 4 with Heroku server.

On both my local computer and heroku server, "rclasses" table exists ( I named it ). I can see the file exists in local by putting this command.

```
psql -dbname= myappname_development
```

and

```
\d
```

And I see several tables I generated there.

How can I know the table exists in Heroku server as well?

Second, in my console( Command : rails console ), I put individual item by doing manually.

```
object = Rclass.new ( :something => "something" , :something2 => "something2")
object.save
```

and repeat this with different values.Here Rclass is the model name.

Where can I see my entries? :) And it seems this data was not transferred to Heroku ( I was hoping it would be. Only the structure itself-probablly called table itself right- was generated ) So how can I see the my entry in local and Heroku server and how can I export the data in my local machine to Heroku server?

I always do

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Please help me!! :) If there is any code I have to put here, let me know!

Comment: Excellent article about import/export data to/from heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: Hi Marcus! I followed your instruction! So I encountered the permission issue with app sushi. Where can I install it? or How can I get the permission on app sushi? :) Can you suggest me anything?

Comment: Sushi is the name of the app they use as an example, you have to provide your own app everywhere they mention sushi

Comment: @Marcus Why don't put that as an answer? That was really helpful and *was* an answer. It will help future visitor